# Will a Liechtenstein stamp really get me denied entrance to Finland?

Tags: finland

I am a frequent traveller who enjoys getting my passport stamped (when I have pages, anyway).  On a visit to Liechtenstein, I received a stamp  from  Liechtensteinish officials (purely for souvenir purposes since there isn't any actual border control in the principality).

I was surprised to recently see that Wikipedia [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passport) (without citation):

> Some travellers "collect" immigration stamps in passports, and will choose to enter or exit countries via different means (for example, land, sea or air) in order to have different stamps in their passports. Some countries, such as Liechtenstein,[61] that do not stamp passports may provide a passport stamp on request for such "memory" purposes. However, such memorial stamps can preclude the passport bearer from travelling to certain countries. **For example, Finland consistently rejects what they call 'falsified passports', where travelers have been refused visas or entry due to memorial stamps and are required to renew their passports**.

Will my stamp from Liechtenstein *really* get me denied access to Finland? I'm sceptical of the claim, as its uncited, but then again, many countries have odd border rules.

Comment: Just courious: Where in Liechtenstein did you find a border police post to have your passport stamped. When driving in from Switzerland, AFAIK there is only one bridge and you need to make sure you don't miss the sign saying that you are not in Liechtenstein.

Comment: @TorstenS You will see a border police post entering through Zollamt Schaanwald (from Austria).

Comment: @Neusser Do they have stamps though? I thought you coould only get it at the Tourist Office. Switzerland also doesn't have stamps at land borders, even though passport checks are frequent at Major crossings for Long-distance buses in particular

Comment: @Crazydre No idea, I just drove through and didn't stop :)

Answer (score 2):

After reading the linked question, I think there will be a difference between an official stamp from the Liechtenstein border police and a stamp which has nothing to do with border control but is given by any tourist place or any festival.

I'd agree that official travel documents like a passport are not the right place to collect pure memorial stamps, yet what you got IMHO is not a memorial stamp in the sense of what Wikipedia quotes there.

Comment: -1: How is this an answer to the question? This might be a comment on why this shouldn't be marked as a duplicate (and maybe it's not an exact duplicate, but a.) the question is answered there, and b.) if memorial stamps don't keep you from being admitted, then real stamps won't either).

Comment: a) No, the question is not answered there as the other question is about memorial stamps while the OP is asking about non-required but official stamps. So you're right, it's an argument why this is not a duplicate. b) You get it wrong. Memorial stamps will likely prevent you, real stamps won't.